# Getting an error when deploying rails app. 'can't activate pg (~>0.18), already activated by pg 1.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am trying to follow the Railsbridge Intallfest and when trying to deploy my first rails app to heroku. I keep getting the following error message:

```
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the 
gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its 
version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Caused by:
Gem::LoadError: can't activate pg (~> 0.18), already activated pg-
1.0.0. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.
```

I tried editing the gem file (see below), I tried deleting gemfile.lock and running bundle install again. I tried deleting all gems and re-installing only pg 0.18. I was working on this all night and couldn't find any answers. I'm basically brand new to this so please help! Thank you!!

In the gem list, it shows this: pg (0.21.0, 0.18.0)

Here is my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
"https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.1.4'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
group :development, :test do
gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
end
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.7'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported 
runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: 
https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: 
https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a 
debugger console
gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
# Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
end

group :development do
# Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> 
anywhere in the code.
gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running 
in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring'
gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: What command causes the error?

Comment: See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264765/heroku-with-rails-5-error-gemloaderror-specified-postgresql-for-database-ad

Answer (score 0):

I actually found the solution via some help from the odin project gitter chat.

Basically, I had to learn more about how git worked.

The piece I was missing:
-update the Gemfile to look like this: gem “pg”, “<1.0”
-delete gemfile.lock 
-run the bundle install 
-add -A
-commit

^I kept hearing about commit and I thought it meant you just need to commit to what you are doing! LOL  I think I was just missing what was already common knowledge for most experienced programmers.