# rake assets:precompile, rake aborted - error pushing to heroku - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, heroku-postgres

I've been trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails app to Heroku but have been running into errors. Really appreciate the help in advance!

I've been following the instructions in this link to deploy my app: http://curriculum.railsbridge.org/intro-to-rails/deploying_to_heroku

I changed my gemfile to the following and then ran

```html
bundle install --without production
```

Gem-file:

```html
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end
# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.3'

# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platform: :mri
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.0.5'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.7'
gem 'devise', '~> 4.2'

gem 'toastr-rails', "~> 1.0"

gem 'omniauth', '~> 1.6'
gem 'omniauth-facebook', '~> 4.0'
gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.1.0'
gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.4'

gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'momentjs-rails', '~> 2.17'
```

Below is the build log from Heroku. It is complaining about not having gem 'pg' in the gemfile, but I have definitely added it and also did bundle install.

```html
Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

Build log from heroku

```html
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.3.4
###### WARNING:
       You have the `.bundle/config` file checked into your repository
       It contains local state like the location of the installed bundle
       as well as configured git local gems, and other settings that should
       not be shared between multiple checkouts of a single repo. Please
       remove the `.bundle/` folder from your repo and add it to your `.gitignore` file.
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-configuration
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.15.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler (1.15.2) is older than the version that created the lockfile (1.16.1). We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       <Fetching a ton of things.....>
       Bundle complete! 25 Gemfile dependencies, 82 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development, test and production were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
       Post-install message from paperclip:
       ##################################################
       #  NOTE FOR UPGRADING FROM 4.3.0 OR EARLIER       #
       ##################################################
       Paperclip is now compatible with aws-sdk >= 2.0.0.
       If you are using S3 storage, aws-sdk >= 2.0.0 requires you to make a few small
       changes:
       * You must set the `s3_region`
       * If you are explicitly setting permissions anywhere, such as in an initializer,
       note that the format of the permissions changed from using an underscore to
       using a hyphen. For example, `:public_read` needs to be changed to
       `public-read`.
       For a walkthrough of upgrading from 4 to 5 and aws-sdk >= 2.0 you can watch
       http://rubythursday.com/episodes/ruby-snack-27-upgrade-paperclip-and-aws-sdk-in-prep-for-rails-5
       Bundle completed (25.24s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v6.11.1-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
       /tmp/build_b5def35a67e05bc1af4c0bb3931868f9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-5.0.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:176:in `rescue in spec'
       
<more errors here>
       /tmp/build_b5def35a67e05bc1af4c0bb3931868f9/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-12.3.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: This gem is skipped because of `--skip production` switch (it is included only in _production_ group). Try just `bundle install` and see the result.

Comment: You could also avoid this problem (and many problems down the road) by install PostgreSQL in your development and test environments. There are a lot of portability issues that ActiveRecord won't protect you from so developing and testing with one database while deploying with another is madness.

Comment: @Mareq, i did bundle install, and still had the same error telling me to Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile

Comment: @StellaHan Rails will load Bundler groups depending on your `RAILS_ENV`.  Make sure `RAILS_ENV` is defined appropriately in your Heroku configuration and make sure the corresponding Bundler group has the `pg` gem in it.

For instance, if you are deploying to `RAILS_ENV=staging`, then the `pg` gem must be in the `staging` bundler group.

`gem 'pg', groups: %w[staging production]`

I think you have not specified `RAILS_ENV` in your Heroku configuration, therefore Rails is default to `development` and you do not have `pg` in your `development` Bundler group.

Comment: Try adding a specific pg version. In particular not the last one (1.0.0) but the previous one (0.21.0).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Heroku with rails 5 error Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264765/heroku-with-rails-5-error-gemloaderror-specified-postgresql-for-database-ad)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer you want, but you should avoid using `sqlite3` for development and then switching to `pg` for production because of portability issues and general headaches in general.

I recommend you recreate your app in the following manner:

`rails new name-of-app --database=postgresql`

In development you always want to think through to the final product. If you know you are going to be deploying it to Heroku, then you know you are going to need PostgreSQL or if you did not know, now you do.

You always want your dev environment to resemble as closely as possible your production environment.