# Trying to figure out why my rails app crashes in heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am brand new to heroku, trying to deploy a Rails app for the first time. When I open it, it crashes. Here is the logs, just wondering if anybody can make sense of it?

```
 018-02-28T03:49:38.908155+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908156+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908160+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917703+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908161+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908153+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917707+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917709+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917710+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-02-28T03:50:00.911567+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d5674160-7991-4e20-a8c2-9037cd14fca0 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:50:02.294872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=5aac6d0b-2974-40ac-8fc3-fd314fcedba2 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908155+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908156+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908160+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917703+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908161+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908153+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917707+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917709+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917710+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-02-28T03:50:00.911567+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d5
674160-7991-4e20-a8c2-9037cd14fca0 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:50:02.294872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=5aac6d0b-2974-40ac-8fc3-fd314fcedba2 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908155+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command.rb:44:in `invoke'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908156+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908160+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917703+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908161+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908153+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917707+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917709+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917710+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-02-28T03:50:00.911567+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d5
674160-7991-4e20-a8c2-9037cd14fca0 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:50:02.294872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=5aac6d0b-2974-40ac-8fc3-fd314fcedba2 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:52:46.845758+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=f695bff2-745d-4f14-af52-55b246316e7a fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:52:50.098411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=b7af71af-e036-47b3-8c35-d9f841971cd2 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908160+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917703+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908161+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908153+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917707+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917709+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917710+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-02-28T03:50:00.911567+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d5674160-7991-4e20-a8c2-9037cd14fca0 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:50:02.294872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=5aac6d0b-2974-40ac-8fc3-fd314fcedba2 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:52:46.845758+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=f695bff2-745d-4f14-af52-55b246316e7a fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:52:50.098411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=b7af71af-e036-47b3-8c35-d9f841971cd2 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
Disconnected from log stream. There may be events happening that you do not see here! Attempting to reconnect...
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908160+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `require'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917703+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908161+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.908153+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.1.4/lib/rails/command/base.rb:63:in `perform'
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917707+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.1.4 application starting in production 
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917709+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-02-28T03:49:38.917710+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-02-28T03:50:00.911567+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=d5674160-7991-4e20-a8c2-9037cd14fca0 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:50:02.294872+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=5aac6d0b-2974-40ac-8fc3-fd314fcedba2 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:52:46.845758+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=f695bff2-745d-4f14-af52-55b246316e7a fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-02-28T03:52:50.098411+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=fidirect-api.herokuapp.com request_id=b7af71af-e036-47b3-8c35-d9f841971cd2 fwd="199.116.73.196" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Comment: is this app deployed correctly?

Comment: Yes. When I run heroku run rails console in a terminal, I get an error saying that postgresql is specified as the database adapter but it is not included in the gemfile. However, I  just checked the gemfile and gemfile.lock and its in both. I switched the db from sqlite to postgres as required by heroku, but im not sure if this is somehow causing an issue

Comment: Did you run `heroku run rake db:migrate` after deployment?

Comment: When I do that I get the same error:

Comment: Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).

Comment: did you commit code after adding `pg gem` . if not you just need to commit you `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` and deploy again.

Comment: The latest commit has postgres, and thats what I deployed. However, I just realized I dont have postgres installed locally on my computer. Could that be the issue?

Comment: check if your `pg gem` installed locally.

Comment: It did not @PardeepSaini

Comment: then you need to install `postgres` locally and then install the `pg gem`. Issue with heroku is that all gems must be installed locally before you deployed to heroku, because heroku reads your `Gemfile.lock` files to install dependencies.

Comment: If your issue about `gem pg` with Heroku then follow this answer it might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/48264843/4172515

Comment: Thanks! I will try that

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `postgres` locally because without `postgres` you can't install `pg gem`. So after installing `postgres` install `pg gem` so bundler made entries in your `Gemfile.lock`. Issue with heroku is that all gems must be installed locally before you deployed to heroku, because heroku reads your `Gemfile.lock` file to install dependencies.